# Facebox login form loading my entire index page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebox

I'm not good with javascript.  I'm using a facebox login form based on this tutorial:

http://freecss.info/css-tutorials/jquery-ajax-contact-form-in-facebox/

Error handling works fine.  Problem = If there are no errors, my header("location: index.php") loads in the facebox.

**How do I close the facebox and reload the page?**

Comment: What do you want to load in the facebox?

Comment: I'm loading the login form with validation.  If no errors I want the facebox to close and refresh the current page.

Comment: There is a zip package on the link provided.  My code is 99% the same.  The difference being: 
//Finished logging in.  Send to homepage
   header("location: ../index.php");
   exit();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the behavior of the responses so that you can control when to show errors on success and when to redirect, check these changes:
**sendemail.php:**

```
<?php

/************************
* Variables you can change
*************************/

$mailto = "mikkaclarke@hotmail.com";
$cc = "";
$bcc = "";
$subject = "Email subject";
$vname = "BrightCherry enquiry";


/************************
* do not modify anything below unless you know PHP/HTML/XHTML
*************************/


$email = $_POST['email'];
$resp['error'] = FALSE; // by default there are no errors

function validateEmail($email)
{
   if(eregi('^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?$', $email))
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}


if((strlen($_POST['name']) < 1 ) || (strlen($email) < 1 ) || (strlen($_POST['message']) < 1 ) || validateEmail($email) == FALSE){
    $resp['error'] = TRUE;
    $emailerror .= 'Error:';

    if(strlen($_POST['name']) < 1 ){
        $emailerror .= '<li>Enter name</li>';
    }

    if(strlen($email) < 1 ){
        $emailerror .= '<li>Enter email</li>';
    }

    if(validateEmail($email) == FALSE) {
        $emailerror .= '<li>Enter valid email</li>';
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['message']) < 1 ){
        $emailerror .= '<li>Enter message</li>';
    }
    $err = "<div id='emailerror'><ul>$emailerror</ul></div>";
    $resp['error_msg'] = $err;
} else {
    $emailerror .= "<span>Your email has been sent successfully!</span>";



    // NOW SEND THE ENQUIRY

    $timestamp = date("F j, Y, g:ia");

    $messageproper ="\n\n" .
        "Name: " .
        ucwords($_POST['name']) .
        "\n" .
        "Email: " .
        ucwords($email) .
        "\n" .
        "Comments: " .
        $_POST['message'] .
        "\n" .
        "\n\n" ;

        $messageproper = trim(stripslashes($messageproper));
        mail($mailto, $subject, $messageproper, "From: \"$vname\" <".$_POST['e_mail'].">\nReply-To: \"".ucwords($_POST['first_name'])."\" <".$_POST['e_mail'].">\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() );

}
echo json_encode($resp);
?>
```

And your `ajaxForm` in your contact and index (i don't know why you need it there):

```
$('#submitform').ajaxForm({
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(resp) {
        if(resp.error)
            $('#error').html(resp.error_msg).fadeIn('slow');
        else
            window.location = 'index.php';
    }
});
```

What I've done is the following:

1. Validate the form and echo the results as `json`
2. if there are errors, set the error flag and the error message
3. else just pass the error flag set to false
4. in your success method, if you the error flag is set to true then display errors
5. else redirect!

Comment: I'm not sure why index needs the code as well.  I'm having issues trying to get this to work.  My submit button doesn't click.

Comment: Chrome says: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (" jquery.js:12

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I figured out my issues.  Mostly was from discerning between resp.error and resp.error_msg.

Comment: Glad it worked, please have a read of this [article](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/) ;)